# Why is new Node not being created?

Tags: c

I have following method in the c code.

```
    void add(int number)
    {
    Node node1; // a new node should be created
    createNodeRelationshipBetween(&node1, current);
    setData(&node1, number);
    setCurrentNode(&node1);
    incrementSize();
    printf("Inserted Node [data:- %d, Node address:- %p\n", node1.data, &node1);
   }
```

where Node is defined as

```
typedef struct node
 {
    struct node *prior;
    struct node *next;
    int data;
 } Node;
```

I am calling add() in a loop. My understanding is that every time i call add(i), a new Node should be created. Instead when i print the address of node1, it is same every time. Can someone please explain where the error is and how do i create a new node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function does create a new `Node`, but only as a local variable.  When your `add()` function returns, it vanishes.  If you're calling `add()` in a loop, the address of the `Node` object on the stack is always going to be the same.

To make your new `Node` persistent, you will need to allocate some persistent memory for it - check out [`malloc(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and [`free(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free).  A quick example:

```
Node *node1 = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

You will need to keep track of the `node1` pointer so as not to introduce a memory leak.  You can use `free(3)` later to destroy the allocation.

Answer (score 5):

That code is creating a Node structure on the stack. As soon as you leave the function that node is destroyed. The pointer is the same because it is pointing to the same local variable on the stack each time. The solution is to allocate space on the heap for the variable with something like [malloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ewkz86d.aspx):

```
malloc( sizeof( Node ) )
```

You can then use the returned pointer in the way you have. Don't forget to [free](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we1whae7.aspx) the nodes when you're done.

Comment: I think the last sentence of this answer should read: Don't *forget* to free the nodes when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

`node1` is a local variable, so it gets recreated on every call to the function, and destroyed on every return.

Answer (score 1):

node1 is local to your add function - if you want it to persist outside of that function, then allocate off the heap using malloc

Answer (score 1):

A new `Node` is not created by the line `Node node1;`.  This line merely declares a variable whose scope is limited to the lifetime of the function (that is, the variable is placed on the stack).  When the function returns, `node1` no longer exists.

Since you are calling `add()` in a tight loop, what is probably happening is that each call to `add()` is getting assigned the same stack range and `node1` just happens to have the same address every time the function is called.

If each invocation of `add()` needs to have a unique `node1` with a unique address, then you will want to dynamically allocate the object with `malloc`.